# best way to upload a large image

Tags: image-processing, html5-canvas

I have an image captured every second from my web cam of size 720x576.

I ultimately display this in a canvas control via my server.

I convert this jpeg to bytes (31553) and upload it using WCF.

I have been debating whether to split this image into 4 smaller images and uploading them 1 after the other. When each image is uploaded it is drawn on a hidden canvas.  Then once all 4 images are uploaded I update the visible canvas with the 'cached' canvas.

Will this be a better/faster way to upload the image by splitting into 4 images or will it make no difference at all?

I will write and conduct tests for this code now but thought I would set myself up to be educated as to what the done/accepted wisdom is.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look from compression point of view, the total size of the four images should be more than one image. You can imagine as compressing redundant information 4 times. If you keep on dividing and compressing, you may end up sending every pixel.

Another way to look at this is from network's point of view. Many times internet bandwidth is the limiting factor, so probably sending one file would be best (as it would be smaller). In another scenario, there might be congestion in the network so multiple data streams (if you upload them in parallel and the server is multi-threaded) are more likely to get a larger chunk of the bandwidth.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your very interesting points. All well taken.  I know that if the image has a higher contrast the byte array gets larger.  I had thought about uploading just a jpeg with only the pixels that have changed and applying to the canvas that way. Also, the bandwidth is a problem for this 1 client which is why I considered sending smaller packets.  I may just have to say a particular bandwidth needs to be in place for the uplaod. At present he uses 0.5mb but even if it was 1mb that would be enough for the upload.  Though I am not sure how common that is for people with broadband.

Comment: I know that if the image has a higher contrast the byte array gets larger.  I had thought about uploading just a jpeg with only the pixels that have changed and applying to the canvas that way. Also, the bandwidth is a problem for this 1 client which is why I considered sending smaller packets. At present he uses 0.5mb but even if it was 1mb that would be enough for the upload.  Though I am not sure how common that is for people with broadband?  I will leave this it un-ticked for a few hours in case a better answer comes through (just in case!)

Comment: lol - not sure what happened to my posting there. It seems to have mutated and split!

Comment: if you are sending a sequence of images, it would be interesting to look at MPEG codecs, they are precisely meant for that, they have a block matching algorithm and send only motion vectors corresponding to the blocks for a certain number of frames before transmitting a new frame altogether, however if motion is too much in a second, I am not sure how will it work

Comment: HI, again thanks for your continued time and suggestions. If I am showing jpegs sequentially via my server how would/should I adapt a codec for this?  (Total Novice :) )..